# Facebook Pixel Issue

Tags: wordpress, facebook, pixel

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a facebook pixel firing from a Divi theme button on wordpress at https://www.hannahhumphries.com

I've followed the steps outlined on [https://stonypeaksdigital.com/triggering_facebook_pixel_events_inline_action/](https://www.hannahhumphries.com) and set everything up as outlined within that tutorial but when I load pixel helper I still get a ! error (see screenshot)

I'm hoping this is just because it's hidden behind an onclick and that someone can verify that it's actually working for me as the client thinks it's still not functional.

If it isn't working any help would be appreciated, I am 'new' to facebook pixels so just worried I'm overlooking something...

I've pasted the code below and it's hooked into the button which has the id 'fb_pixel_initiatecheckout'

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fb_pixel_initiatecheckout").click(function(){
  fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout');
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: _“and it's hooked into the button which has the id 'fb_pixel_initiatecheckout'”_ - not its not, because you used the _class_ selector. (FYI, IDs have to be unique within a document, but you have several elements with that ID.)

Comment: Apparently this is the only way to do it with Divi theme as the buttons aren't actually 'buttons' per say, are you suggesting I just need to change the 'fb_pixel_initiatecheckout' to something else? That's the only element I have using that class, and is as the tutorial suggests it should be...

Comment: _“That's the only element I have using that class”_ - no, again: You do not have even a single element with that class in the page you referred to. Are you not aware of the difference between an ID and a class?

Comment: I did have, it seems the theme cache was tripping it up, I've just flushed it and it's working now, thanks for the help anyway, and apologies for the confusion but you not being able to see it helped me investigate why and solve it :)